# Some of customer login in magento 2.1 welcome Undefined is getting

Tags: magento-2.1, php-5.4

Once the customer logged in to our site Welcome Undefined message is getting in Header rather than customer name, Some of the customers are working but some old customers its throwing Welcome Undefined message in magento 2.1.

Can anyone help me to solve this please.

Comment: Is the same thing happend after page reload?

Comment: yes , page reload also its coming same for old registered customers, if suppose i have registered new customer , for him its showing correct customer name. thanks